# Finding out what VMware machine a Windows server is running on?

Tags: windows, vmware-vsphere

Is it possible to find out the name of the VMware machine (host) that a specific (not necessarily local) windows server (guest) is running on using the command line or power shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerCLI (https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/) is VMware's implementation of PowerShell cmdlets to manage VMware.
https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/PowerCLI41U1/html/Get-VMHost.html is probably the cmdlet you are looking for.

Hope this helps.

Thanks, Tim.